# Optimization of strcpy at the assembler level

Tags: disassembly

I'm writing small C programs to teach myself how to use GDB to disassemble code.  The C in question is:

```
void function( char **pointer )
{
   *pointer = malloc(100);
   strcpy(*pointer,"This is text");
}
```

The disassembly is:

```
0x400620:    push   %rbp
0x400621:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x400624:    sub    $0x10,%rsp
0x400628:    mov    %rdi,-0x8(%rbp)
0x40062c:    mov    $0x64,%edi
0x400631:    callq  0x4004f0 <malloc@plt>
0x400636:    mov    %rax,%rdx
0x400639:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
0x40063d:    mov    %rdx,(%rax)
0x400640:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
0x400644:    mov    (%rax),%rax
0x400647:    movabs $0x2073692073696854,%rcx
0x400651:    mov    %rcx,(%rax)
0x400654:    movl   $0x74786574,0x8(%rax)
0x40065b:    movb   $0x0,0xc(%rax)
0x40065f:    leaveq 
0x400660:    retq
```

I understand the prologue: `0x400620`-`0x400624`. I also understand that the pointer is being initialized to 100 char here: `0x400628`-`0x40063d`.

I cannot seem to figure out what `strcpy` is doing and I do not understand how to examine the contents of the addresses listed in `0x400647` and `0x400654`.

Can someone help me work through this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I assume that you understood the stack-frame initialization part and the call to the `malloc` through the PLT (Procedure Linking Table).

```
0x400636:    mov    %rax,%rdx
```

This line take the return code of the `malloc` function and save it in the `rdx` register. This value correspond to the address of the memory space you just created through the `malloc` call.

```
0x400639:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
```

Here, you take the first argument of the function we are in (`char **pointer` according to your source code) and it is stored in the `rax` register.

```
0x40063d:    mov    %rdx,(%rax)
```

This line transfert the address of the allocated memory area to the `pointer` variable.

```
0x400640:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
```

An (unnecessary) copy of the first argument of `function` in `rax` (the register already store this value, probably a glitch of the compiler that did not optimized enough).

```
0x400644:    mov    (%rax),%rax
```

Set `rax` as the address pointed by `pointer`.

```
0x400647:    movabs $0x2073692073696854,%rcx
```

To understand that, you need to decompose this magic number `0x2073692073696854` and cut it into pieces. Lets use `gdb` for that:

```
(gdb) p /c 0x54
$1 = 84 'T'
(gdb) p /c 0x68
$2 = 104 'h'
(gdb) p /c 0x69
$3 = 105 'i'
(gdb) p /c 0x73
$4 = 115 's'
(gdb) p /c 0x20
$5 = 32 ' '
(gdb) ...
```

I guess that you start to see what is the meaning of this big number by now...

```
0x400651:    mov    %rcx,(%rax)
```

On this line, the previous magic number is stored in the address pointed by `pointer`.

```
0x400654:    movl   $0x74786574,0x8(%rax)
```

This last magic number is, in fact, the end of your string (it correspond to the word `text`).

```
0x40065b:    movb   $0x0,0xc(%rax)
```

Copy the `\0` character to end the string at the right place (`0xc` is the size of the string and `rax` is the start address of the string).

Comment: The text seems to be in the wrong order in the register value - that is because x86/64 stores values in little-endian

Comment: I forgot to tell about that, wasn't it obvious ?

Comment: The likelihood of it being obvious for people not that deep into assembly are fairly low. I try to read answers here as if I knew next to nothing and saw that as a possible follow-up question

Comment: This pretty much explains it.  I was thinking that the string was stored at instead of the string was those funny numbers.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the hex digits at `0x400647` and convert them to ascii characters, byte by byte (2 digits by 2 digits). Does the result ring a bell?

Since the source for your `strcpy` is a constant string, the compiler optimizes "copy the contents of a static string, byte by byte, until `\0` is reached" to "fill the target with the expected bytes in the fastest way possible".

If you want to see what the memory looks like after the optimized `strcpy`, set a breakpoint on `0x40065b` and enter `x/20b *$rax`.

Comment: Because I did not use any optimization flags it never occurred to me that the compiler was taking liberties and optimizing.  thanks for pointing this out Guntram.