# Explain struct access in assembly?

Tags: disassembly, assembly, compiler-optimization

I am having trouble understanding working with structs in assembly from disassembly. 
can you please explain the code below. Disassembly below:

[image: disassembly snippet]

Source code:

[image: source code snippet]

Comment: Could you please copy and paste the disassembly instead of posting screenshots? It'd really help others in the future as it improves indexing by search engines. Thanks!

Comment: apologies for not being clear in my comment. I meant that you should *edit* your own question to replace the screenshots with the textual form. For this question this would seem to apply to both screenshots. Thank you.

Comment: previous discussion on this optimization: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10839/

Comment: I downvoted your question because images of text are *not useful at all*. There is no need to supply this text as images. Will remove the downvote if you replace the images with text.

Answer (score 2):

This is manual string assignment. Notice how all DWORDs are composed of printable characters? hit <kbd>r</kbd> in IDA to convert the hex values to string characters.

This code seems to be assigning strings into different stack addresses, 4 characters at a time. This is a common optimization over calling a function that iterates over strings byte by byte.

As others pointed out, this optimization is usually called "loop unrolling" as it unrolls several iterations of a loop into sequential assembly, however I often find that type of direct string characters assignment to be more commonly the output of a code similar to the following:

```
char str[] = "this is a string";
```

Comment: Key word: unrolled loop. Probably an inlined `memmove` (or `strcpy`).

Comment: @0xC0000022L does it have to be, though? I think it can also be a direct assignment, say `char a[] = "this is a string";`, no?

Answer (score 2):

This is called inlining. strcpy was substituted by mov instructions, because compiler decided that in such way code will run faster.

Answer (score 1):

the optimizations mantras  of the answers got me intrigued so i thought i'll check what actual optimizations are being done  on the code (OP appears to be beginner and i doubted OP  would be capable of optimizing at all )

it appears this is default compilation without optimization enabled in gcc

**gcc version 8.1.0 (i686-win32-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)**

**visual studio 2017 15.7.3** doesn't do this kind of code at all whether optimized or not

with optimizations disabled vs resorts to calling strcpy ()

```
:\>cl /nologo /Zi booky.cpp
booky.cpp

:\>cdb -c ".lines;uf booky!main;q" booky.exe | grep -E "  15|  16|  17"


   15 001c6b35 6850be2100      push    offset booky!__xt_z+0x108 (0021be50)
   15 001c6b3a 8d8530ffffff    lea     eax,[ebp-0D0h]
   15 001c6b40 50              push    eax
   15 001c6b41 e86bb2ffff      call    booky!ILT+3500(_strcpy) (001c1db1) <<<<
   15 001c6b46 83c408          add     esp,8
   16 001c6b49 685cbe2100      push    offset booky!__xt_z+0x114 (0021be5c)
   16 001c6b4e 8d8d62ffffff    lea     ecx,[ebp-9Eh]
   16 001c6b54 51              push    ecx
   16 001c6b55 e857b2ffff      call    booky!ILT+3500(_strcpy) (001c1db1) <<<<
   16 001c6b5a 83c408          add     esp,8
   17 001c6b5d 6868be2100      push    offset booky!__xt_z+0x120 (0021be68)
   17 001c6b62 8d5594          lea     edx,[ebp-6Ch]
   17 001c6b65 52              push    edx
   17 001c6b66 e846b2ffff      call    booky!ILT+3500(_strcpy) (001c1db1)  <<<<
   17 001c6b6b 83c408          add     esp,8
```

optimising for space (O2) or full optimisations (Ox) vs2017 resorts to using sse2 moves

```
:\>cl /Zi /O2 booky.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.14.26430 for x86

:\>cdb -c ".lines;uf booky!main;q" booky.exe | grep -E "  15|  16|  17"
   15 00f7aae4 a158befc00      mov     eax,dword ptr [booky!`string'+0x8 (00fcbe58)]

:\>cdb -c ".lines;uf booky!main;q" booky.exe | grep -A 5 -E "  15|  16|  17"
   15 00f7aae4 a158befc00      mov     eax,dword ptr [booky!`string'+0x8 (00fcbe58)]
   19 00f7aae9 b933000000      mov     ecx,33h
   19 00f7aaee f30f7e0550befc00 movq    xmm0,mmword ptr [booky!`string' (00fcbe50)] <<<<<<<<
   19 00f7aaf6 89442408        mov     dword ptr [esp+8],eax
   19 00f7aafa 0fb60568befc00  movzx   eax,byte ptr [booky!`string'+0x8 (00fcbe68)] <<<<<<<
   19 00f7ab01 8844243a        mov     byte ptr [esp+3Ah],al

:\>cl /Zi /Ox booky.cpp

:\>cdb -c ".lines;uf booky!main;q" booky.exe | grep -A 5 -E "  15|  16|  17"
   15 0138ac74 a198e83d01      mov     eax,dword ptr [booky!__newctype+0x308 (013de898)]
   19 0138ac79 b933000000      mov     ecx,33h
   19 0138ac7e f30f7e0590e83d01 movq    xmm0,mmword ptr [booky!__newctype+0x300 (013de890)]
   19 0138ac86 89442408        mov     dword ptr [esp+8],eax
   19 0138ac8a 0fb605a4e83d01  movzx   eax,byte ptr [booky!__newctype+0x314 (013de8a4)]
   19 0138ac91 8844243a        mov     byte ptr [esp+3Ah],al
```

mingw gcc 8.10 seems to break the strings into dwords even when explicitly disabling optimization with O0

**:>e:\mingw\mingw-w64.bat

:>ls

booky.cpp

:>gcc -g -O0 booky.cpp**

g++ -g -O0 also disassembles to same construct as below

```
:\>objdump -d --start-address 0x4015c0 --stop-address 0x401600 -M intel a.exe

a.exe:     file format pei-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

004015c0 <_main>:
  4015c0:       55                      push   ebp
  4015c1:       89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
  4015c3:       57                      push   edi
  4015c4:       56                      push   esi
  4015c5:       53                      push   ebx
  4015c6:       83 e4 f0                and    esp,0xfffffff0
  4015c9:       81 ec 70 02 00 00       sub    esp,0x270
  4015cf:       e8 ec 01 00 00          call   4017c0 <___main>
  4015d4:       8d 84 24 a4 01 00 00    lea    eax,[esp+0x1a4]
  4015db:       c7 00 50 72 6f 67       mov    DWORD PTR [eax],0x676f7250
  4015e1:       c7 40 04 72 61 6d 6d    mov    DWORD PTR [eax+0x4],0x6d6d6172
  4015e8:       c7 40 08 69 6e 67 00    mov    DWORD PTR [eax+0x8],0x676e69
  4015ef:       8d 84 24 a4 01 00 00    lea    eax,[esp+0x1a4]
  4015f6:       83 c0 32                add    eax,0x32
  4015f9:       c7 00 4e 75 68 61       mov    DWORD PTR [eax],0x6168754e
  4015ff:       c7                      .byte 0xc7
```

to disable this **-fno-builtin-strcpy** needs to be passed to gcc in commandline 
if -fno-builtin-strcpy is passed gcc wont chunk the strings even when compiled with **-O3 optimization**

compilation

```
:\>ls
booky.cpp

:\>g++ -O3 -g -fno-builtin-strcpy -o booky.exe booky.cpp

:\>ls
booky.cpp  booky.exe
```

execution

```
:\>booky.exe
ProgrammingTelecom Billing
```

disassembly

```
:\>objdump -d --start-address=0x402670 --stop-address=0x4026b0 -M intel booky.exe

booky.exe:     file format pei-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00402670 <_main>:
  402670:       55                      push   ebp
  402671:       89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
  402673:       57                      push   edi
  402674:       56                      push   esi
  402675:       53                      push   ebx
  402676:       83 e4 f0                and    esp,0xfffffff0
  402679:       81 ec 80 02 00 00       sub    esp,0x280
  40267f:       e8 ec ef ff ff          call   401670 <___main>
  402684:       8d 74 24 1c             lea    esi,[esp+0x1c]
  402688:       c7 44 24 04 44 40 40    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],0x404044
  40268f:       00
  402690:       8d bc 24 b4 01 00 00    lea    edi,[esp+0x1b4]
  402697:       89 34 24                mov    DWORD PTR [esp],esi
  40269a:       8d 9c 24 b4 01 00 00    lea    ebx,[esp+0x1b4]
  4026a1:       e8 ee fe ff ff          call   402594 <_strcpy>
  4026a6:       8d 44 24 4e             lea    eax,[esp+0x4e]
  4026aa:       c7                      .byte 0xc7
  4026ab:       44                      inc    esp
  4026ac:       24 04                   and    al,0x4
  4026ae:       50                      push   eax
  4026af:       40                      inc    eax
```

an analysed output from radare2

```
|           ; JMP XREF from 0x0040262f (sym.___getmainargs)
|           0x00402671      89e5           mov ebp, esp
|           0x00402673      57             push edi
|           0x00402674      56             push esi
|           0x00402675      53             push ebx
|           0x00402676      83e4f0         and esp, 0xfffffff0
|           0x00402679      81ec80020000   sub esp, 0x280
|           0x0040267f      e8ecefffff     call sym.___main
|           0x00402684      8d74241c       lea esi, [local_1ch]        ; 0x1c ; 28
|           0x00402688      c74424044440.  mov dword [local_4h], str.Programming ; 
[0x404044:4]=0x676f7250 ; "Programming" ; const char * src
|           0x00402690      8dbc24b40100.  lea edi, [local_1b4h]       ; 0x1b4 ; 436
|           0x00402697      893424         mov dword [esp], esi        ; char * dest
|           0x0040269a      8d9c24b40100.  lea ebx, [local_1b4h]       ; 0x1b4 ; 436
|           0x004026a1      e8eefeffff     call sym._strcpy            ;
 char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
|           0x004026a6      8d44244e       lea eax, [local_4eh]        ; 0x4e ; 'N' ; 78
|           0x004026aa      c74424045040.  mov dword [local_4h], str.Nuha_Ali ; 
[0x404050:4]=0x6168754e ; "Nuha Ali" ; const char * src
|           0x004026b2      890424         mov dword [esp], eax        ; char * dest
|           0x004026b5      e8dafeffff     call sym._strcpy            ;
 char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
```